# I need help solving a riddle for my English class, any aid will be greatly appreciated

Tags: riddle

I need help solving a riddle for my English class, any aid will be greatly appreciated.

> When Blood runs black on crimson tides, a sanguine king sets out from this domain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_Blood_Runs_Black#Studio_albums

Comment: And I see you went here too: https://www.jiskha.com/questions/1760825/When-Blood-runs-black-on-crimson-tides-a-sanguine-king-sets-out-from-this-domain

Comment: @Duck nice spotting :P